# Pushable button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a slightly animated pushable button.

My goal is to achieve a button like this:

[image] 
[see the source code (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/JtTM2/3/)

with using exactly one HTML tag and the minimal amount of new CSS features like transform and transition.

However as you see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtTM2/3/); if you click the button at least twice the whole line (and the content beneath) bounces too.
That is ofcourse because of the margin set within the `:active` selector.

My second approach was using the the CSS transform property. That worked perfectly except I still had the need the change the height of the button (which will result in the same problem).

**So my question is**: How can I achieve the same effect without adjusting the positions of other elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve the same effect without adjusting the positions of other elements?

I suggest using `position: relative;` for the button, then set `top: 2px` for `:active` pseudo-class, as follows:

```css
button {
    /* Other styles... */
    position: relative; /* position the element as relative */
    outline: none;      /* Just added for the demo          */
}

button:active {
    top: 2px;  /* move the element without affecting the others' position */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/JtTM2/5/)**.

Comment: I didn't know it was that easy. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: translate` property over `top/left` properties (Check [here](http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/) if you know why) and of course if you don't care about legacy IE browsers:

```
button {
    ....
     transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    ....
}

button:active {
    transform: translatey(2px);
    -moz-transform: translatey(2px);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(2px);
    ...
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JtTM2/8/)</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work if the height is set to 32px within the `:active` psuedo-class. See the sentence before the actual 'question' in the question.

Comment: Why are you declaring height in `:active`?

Comment: The button does not have to move `2px` downwards, but it needs to look like it is being pushed down using the perspective used in the example (see question). Although I probably didn't make that clear enough in my question the most obvious way would be by setting the height minus `2px` in combination with your suggestion.

Comment: @Tim You can increase the height as much as you want for `button` selector however box-shadow bottom pixel must be equal to `translatey` value and you don't need any height to declare in pseudo selectors.